# Provide Azure VM access to multiple Storage Accounts

Tags: azure, permissions, cloud, virtual-machine, storage

I have two storage accounts stinboundclient1 & stinboundclient2 and storage account have initial "**stinbound**" is common for both. Now inside storage accounts there are containers for each environment (dev,test,prod). Now I have a dev Virtual Machine (DevVM) and it needs access to only "dev" container of both storage accounts. What is the best way we can provide read/contributor access to VM using azure policy or custom role or any other approach?

Please do not suggest manual way of providing RBAC permission to VM bcoz its tedious task to provide each container that access as eventually there will 30-40 clients storage accounts.

**Storage Account & Containers:**
stinboundclient1/dev

stinboundclient1/test

stinboundclient1/prod

stinboundclient2/dev

stinboundclient2/test

stinboundclient2/prod

**DevVM** needs access to **stinbound*/dev**

Similarly Test and Prod need access respective containers::

TestVM needs access to stinbound*/test

ProdVM needs access to stinbound*/prod

Comment: please refer this to create a custom policy as per your requirement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-custom-policy-definition

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is actually what Microsoft calls [Attribute-based Access Control (ABAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/conditions-overview).

That way, you can grant access to a scope and add a particular condition for this access to be effective on the name of the container, a tag to be present, etc.

This feature is still in Preview though.